# getting an error pop-up window on optional argument in UDF VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, optional-parameters

I'm getting a pop-up error window while trying to use an optional argument on a user defined function.
The UDF have 3 arguments, first and third arguments are required while the second one is the optional one. the code is similar to this

```
function test (p1 as string, optional p2 as string="", p3 as string) as boolean
...
test=true
End function
```

The moment I finish the function statement an error window pops-up with the following message

> Compilation error:
>
> It was expected: Optional

Pointing to the p3 argument.

Although the fast way is to move the optional argument to the third one it is not very user friendly for my udf and I am guessing if there is any other approach to solve this issue or if I am getting this error because there is something I have to set up in my configuration

Thank you

Comment: There is no other way, as @chill60 also stated. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/optional "If the parameter list contains an optional parameter, every parameter that follows it must also be optional."

Comment: It is nothing to do with configuration it is the syntactic rule that you have to follow. The only other options are to make p3 optional OR to make p2 compulsory.

Comment: Thanks chill60 and Paul for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the function declaration to

```
Function test (p1 As String, p3 As String, Optional p2 As String="") As Boolean
```

You can't have compulsory arguments following optional arguments